# How to add [innerHTML] on variable {{list.TAG}} in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am fetching value from `home.ts` and using `ngFor`. I am showing the value on `home.html`.

Everything is working fine but the html data is not rendering its properties, as I am not using `[innerHTML]` till now.

How can I render my code with html properties?

My current **home.html** code

```
<div id="c1"> {{list.TAG}} </div>

<!-- below line of code renders the data with html properties -->
<div id="c1" [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

**home.ts** code

```
          this._http.get(this._url + this.SNO + "&" + this.randomno, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.list = data.json();

// this works fine on html
this.theHtmlString = `<b>hii</b>`
```

Currently this is how my data is getting loaded, see below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using DOMSanitizer. Angular may not trust the HTML string passed to {{list.TAG}}

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml

```
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

sanitize(html) {
    return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html) ;
}
```

Then your HTML can be

```
<div id="c1" [innerHTML]="sanitize(list.TAG)"></div>
```

Comment: no, read my question again,  `// this works fine on html
this.theHtmlString = `<b>hii</b>``  this is already working fine, problem is with `{{list.TAG}}`

Comment: @user2828442 I understand but my answer is still valid. You should use [innerHTML] & DomSanitizer to ensure the HTML passed from the object is trusted. Is there a reason you would like this in the {{}} syntax?

Comment: because list is array and on html i am using ngFor to render each object 1 by 1, list.tag where tag is the object

Comment: i have also posted a seperate question which you can find here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389762/froala-editor-no-data-is-getting-fetch-except-data-on-first-line